# ANR but the application isn't doint anything

Tags: android

I'm currently loosing my head on a **** problem !
For about one week, I've tried to put any task which can be quite long to asynctask but problem is still here.

[Here](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/147906Captured.png) DDMS trace recorded :

[image]

This was just before ANR.
We can see that main thread isn't doing anything. The only thing I see it's MessageQueue.nativePollOnce() but didn't known why is it used for ?

Any help would be very, very appreciated.

Thx.

Comment: The MessageQueue is a fundamental tool used in every app, it isn't the direct culprit something else is causing the MessageQueue to lock up...  Have you walked through your code with break statements to find where the problem starts?  Also it's impossible to help you without seeing the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sam for your answer and sorry for the delay of my response.

I just found yesterday by reading the Android documentation of Service.
[Android Service Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)
In the onStartCommand, I've replaced the

```
return startId;
```

by

```
return START_NOT_STICKY;
```

I found the solution thanks to this :

> An example of such a service would be one that polls for data from a
>   server: it could schedule an alarm to poll every N minutes by having
>   the alarm start its service.

That's exactly what my application is doing.
But, if this example wasn't given, I think I will be still looking for a solution, because I hadn't understand as well as I wanted the explanation of these return statment ...

In any case, I don't have anymore ANR, and it's awesome !!! :D